# will fetch/merge not work if files are added or deleted in GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I made two changes to my `remote repository` in `GitHub`, by adding a new `file` and deleting a `old file` (by using the Web interface of `GitHub`). when I do :

```
git fetch origin master
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From github.com:TommyHilly/programFiles
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
git merge origin/master
Already up-to-date.
```

whenever new files are added or deleted, `git pull` only works (`git fetch/merge fails`).

```
$git pull
From github.com:TommyHilly/programFiles
   b598c97..531d466  master     -> origin/master
Updating b598c97..531d466
Fast-forward
 README.txt |   2 ++
 a.out      | Bin 8496 -> 0 bytes
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.txt
 delete mode 100755 a.out
```

But when I have some files edited (nothing new added or deleted), `git fetch` and `merge` works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this how `git` works?

EDIT:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:TommyHilly/programFiles.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TommyHilly/programFiles.git (push)
```

EDIT 2:
Just doing `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master` seems to work. But I dont understand what is going on?

But `git fetch origin master` followed by `git merge origin/master` did not work?

Comment: Have you tried `git merge` instead of `git merge origin/master`? It looks like by adding the refspec `master` to the `fetch` command, you're just fetching to `FETCH_HEAD` instead of the `origin/master` remote tracking branch. (No idea why this works for you when you don't add and delete files...)

Comment: I get this when I do `git merge`: `$ git merge
fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that `git pull` is really just `git fetch` plus `git merge`.  But there are a bunch of caveats.

#### git fetch

When you run:

```
$ git fetch origin master
```

this "means":

```
$ git fetch origin master:FETCH_HEAD
```

which tells `git fetch` to run over to `origin` and ask them—github, in this case, and I will use "them" and "they" here to refer to `origin`, so that "it" means "your fetch"—what they have for branch `master`.  Whatever they have, it brings over, but it puts that under the local special name `FETCH_HEAD`.

If you run instead:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

this "means" for `fetch` to run over to `origin` and ask them about *all* their branches, and bring them all over as "remote branches".  If they have branches "master" and "experiment", it brings those over as "remote branches" `origin/master` and `origin/experiment`.

#### git merge

First, `git merge` always merges into your *current branch* (the one marked with a `*` in `git branch` output).<sup>1</sup>  In other words, it knows where to merge *to*.  You need to tell it where to merge *from*, though.

If you run:

```
$ git merge
```

with no arguments, it has to figure out what commit-ID you want to "merge from".  It does this by looking for a configuration variable, `merge.defaultToUpstream`.  If you get:

```
fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.
```

this means `merge.defaultToUpstream` is not set, or is set to `false` instead of `true`.

If you run `git merge name-or-ID`, that tells git merge what to "merge from", so it does not need this special configuration variable.  Hence:

```
$ git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

means "find the commit specified by `FETCH_HEAD`".  Or, if you run:

```
$ git merge origin/master
```

this means "find the commit specified by `origin/master`".

**Important**: If you supply more than one extra argument to `git merge`, it does an "octopus merge" (which I'm not going to describe in this answer).  This means that `git merge origin master` is quite different from `git merge origin/master`.  The slash makes a huge difference, because it changes the `merge` command from a two-argument merge, to a one-argument merge.  (I think it's unfortunate—and/or bad design—that `git pull` has you use exactly those arguments, but they mean something quite different to `git merge`.)

#### Putting them together

So, when do you want to supply `FETCH_HEAD` to `git merge`, and when do you want to supply `origin/master` instead?  Well, go back and re-read the section about **git fetch** above.

The `FETCH_HEAD` method is the old<sup>2</sup> way, in which you tell `git fetch` both the place to fetch from, and the branch to fetch from, and have `git fetch` write the result under the special name `FETCH_HEAD`.  It does not matter what branch you fetched: `git fetch origin inigo_montoya`, `git fetch origin you_killed_my_father`, `git fetch origin inconceivable`: they all come over and get renamed `FETCH_HEAD`, so that's what you merge with.

The `origin/master` method is the new<sup>3</sup> way: you run `git fetch origin` and it just brings *everything* over and you can take your time and browse through "remote branches" at your leisure.  Once you're happy with `origin/master` and ready to merge it in, you merge it in by its (clear, simple, and obvious) name, instead of by `FETCH_HEAD`.

#### git pull

Alas, `git pull`.<sup>4</sup>  The `pull` script still uses the "old way".  When you run `git pull origin master`, or even just `git pull` with no arguments,<sup>5</sup> it winds up running `git fetch origin master`, which makes `git fetch` behave the "old way".  Then it uses `git merge FETCH_HEAD`, which it has to, because it's just run `git fetch` such that fetch did not update `origin/master`.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Even if you're in the "detached HEAD" mode, `git merge` still merges to your "current branch", sort of.  It's just that the closest thing to "current branch" is now "the detached HEAD".

<sup>2</sup>Or maybe "traditional".  I wish it were "obsolete", and that might happen eventually, but for now it's pretty deeply rooted.

<sup>3</sup>And far superior. :-)

<sup>4</sup>I don't like `git pull`.  It's meant as a convenience, and due to its insistence on doing things the "old way", it winds up being *less* convenient, not to mention [one rare but serious bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362425/stage-files-then-remote-add-then-pull-and-my-files-are-gone) it's had for a long time (fixed in git 1.8.4).

<sup>5</sup>With no arguments, `git pull` gets the name of the remote and branch from the configuration for the current branch.  If you're on branch `master`, for instance, git reads `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` to get `origin` and `master`.  These are the same values that make local branch `master` a "tracking branch", tracking remote-branch `origin/master`.  Which is great, except `git pull` forces `git fetch` not to update `origin/master`.  So `git pull` updates your local `master`, but leaves things such that git tells you you're now *ahead* of `origin/master`!  Yuck.  (This is fixed in git 1.8.4; `git fetch` updates remote branches now, even while it writes to `FETCH_HEAD`.)

<sup>6</sup>This is fixed in git 1.9, which might finally make `git pull` a convenience method that's actually *convenient*. :-)

Comment: great explanation. Thanks. can you comment on my EDIT 2 above;

Comment: Ah, be careful with `git merge origin master`, that's what git calls an "octopus merge".  It works because `origin` here "means" `origin/master`, so you're merging `master` with two branches, `origin/master` and `master` (merging with yourself: sounds... kinky :-) ).

Comment: sorry that was a typo, my question was about `git fetch` and `git fetch origin master`. The former with `git merge origin/master` worked but not the latter. any idea why?

Comment: Read the section above on `git fetch`: `git fetch origin master` *prevents* `git fetch` from updating `origin/master` (in git versions older than 1.8.4 anyway).

Comment: I am running `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)` ? is that the whole problem?, so If I install latest version, I shouldn't have to bother between `git fetch` and `git fetch origin master`, since they both work the same?

Comment: Well, the behavior is different in 1.8.4+, but "whole problem" is overstating it: it was *designed* to work like that.  (Personally, I think that particular design bit is dumb, and the design is being changed, so apparently others agree with me there....)  But, since it *is* designed like that, you have to run `git fetch` with at most one more argument (`origin`), for now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46707/discussion-between-user1988876-and-torek)