# What does `git fetch origin master:master` mean?

Tags: git, version-control

What does `git fetch origin master:master` mean?

I mean the `master:master` part: I know what `git fetch origin` means, but what about the `master:master` part?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The arguments after the *remote* (`origin`) are *refspecs*.

Using `master:master` will overwrite your `master` branch; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355802/1256452).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21544585/1256452) for even more about `git fetch`'s behavior with and without refspec arguments.

Comment: Maybe it is not the right place to ask, but it also seems like something to not make a separate question for it. Does `git fetch origin branch:branch` do exactly the same as `git pull` called on `branch`?

Comment: @C.Binair: no, these are—at least potentially—very different, because `git pull` runs *two* commands. The first one is a `git fetch` that acts a lot like `git fetch origin branch:origin/branch`, with the weasel-wording ("acts a lot like") just to handle uncommon special cases. The *second* command that `git pull` runs is up to you: you can have it run `git merge`, or `git rebase`. Both of these are potentially quite different from what `git fetch` will do as both `git merge` and `git rebase` can create *new* commits. Fetch cannot: fetch can only obtain *existing* commits from some other Git.

Comment: @C.Binair: The tricky part here is that both `git merge` and `git rebase` themselves have several special cases where they *don't* need to create new commits, and thus don't bother. **When that happens** the kind of `git fetch` you ask about *can* do the same job. That's because no new commits were needed. Fetch can't create *new* commits, but if the job is simple enough, fetch can do it. It's like having your dog retrieve shoes: if they're where they should be, that works. If it requires going to the shoe store and buying *new* shoes, well, that's asking too much. :-)

Comment: Would ` git fetch --all` covers `git fetch origin master:master ` ?

Comment: @alper: no. The `--all` flag to `git fetch` means *all remotes*. The `master:master` argument to `git fetch origin master:master` is a *refspec*, and refspecs must be provided to override the defaults that `--all` would use for each remote.

Comment: A quick question (and if it turns out not to be quick I'll post it as a new question). Is there a way to do the equivalent of `git fetch origin master:master` without giving the branch name twice? I often do `get fetch origin branch:branch`; I rarely if ever do `git fetch origin branch:different_name`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: other than with an alias or script, no. Obviously trivial to do with a script (or shell alias). Git aliases are weird and messy so I'd use a Git alias that invokes a shell function.