# How to rollback the git repo before the "Initial commit"

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I've done the following:

1. added a new empty repo in GitHub,
2. run `git init` to initialize my local project,
3. run  `git remote add origin` to associate the remote.

However, I then ran `git pull` to pull from the remote, which seems to have removed my project's source code.

How can I recover this lost source code? This project is very important to me...

Comment: `git reset --hard` I try this, but it doesn't work

Comment: `git status` what is the result after this command? if you have commited  data locally, maybe you can see that. By the way, you should commit locally, then push it to github for the first time, other than pull from github.

Comment: Did you try `git reset - - head`?

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10362425/1256452 - what version of git do you have?

Comment: `git fsck --lost-found` is work.The lost files will be restored in `.git/lost-found/other`, but there is so many files, is there any way to recover the directory structure? All of you guys, I really thank you.